# Flat list not being rendered in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In my React native page
Im navigating  from one page to another page  with parameters

so those parameters has id
which will be used to fetch data from endpoint and display that in flat list

```
function Assessments ({route,navigation}) {
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData(file)
  },[]);
  const { file } = route.params;
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
```

file consists of route params(Id)

and fetchdata function triggers that function with the id and fetches data

```
  const fetchData = async (file) => {
    axios.get(`endpoint`)

      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
        setData(response.data)
  


      })
      .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      })

  }
```

and im returning this

```
 return (

<View>
  <Text>okay</Text>


      <FlatList 
            flexGrow= {0}

            minHeight= '20%'
            maxHeight='80%'
      data={data}
      renderItem={showdata}>
      </FlatList>


      </View>
 )
```

and renderitem is

```
  const showdata = ({item}) => {
      <View>
        sdfdsfsdf
      </View>
    
  }
```

but that part isnt even being rendered

not sure where is the issue !

console.log()

```
{
    "id": 19,
    "name": "test1",


}
```

this is how the data from the endpoint is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `showdata` is not returning anything. Please add `return` to it like this.

Here is the full code.

```
function Assessments ({route, navigation}) {
  const { file } = route.params;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData(file)
  },[]);

  const fetchData = async (file) => {
    axios.get(`endpoint`)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
        setData(response.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  const showdata = ({ item }) => {
    //Add return here
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          sdfdsfsdf
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>okay</Text>
      <FlatList 
        //Put all the style within style prop
        style={{flexGrow: 0, minHeight: '20%', maxHeight: '80%'}}
        data={data}
        renderItem={showdata}
      >
      </FlatList>
    </View>
  )

}
```

Comment: added return as well 
still it didnt render the view

Comment: Edited the answer. If the code is still not working., please check whether the axios returned data or not.

Comment: its returning data i can  print the same on console

Comment: Is the return data in form of array? Also, the text `okay` is displayed in the app?

Comment: yes okay is being displayed

Comment: okay its not in array format 
that might be the reason ??

Comment: You may post your data in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250402/discussion-between-john-and-peter-tam).